# How to create 'table in table' in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

e.g.

In clickhouse, I want to create one table like the following structure.

```sql
create table (
time     DateTime,
visits   array(unit) 
)
Engine=memory

the unit struct {
 a          string, 
 btime      int64,  
 c          string, 
 e          string
}
```

How to create the table?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to use [Nested data structure](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/nested-data-structures/nested/):

```sql
CREATE TABLE visits (
  time     DateTime,
  visits   Nested
  (
    a          String, 
    btime      Int64,  
    c          String, 
    e          String    
  )
) ENGINE = Memory;

/* insert test data */
INSERT INTO visits
VALUES 
  (now(), ['a1', 'a2'], [1, 2], ['c1', 'c2'], ['e1', 'e2']),
  (now(), ['a11', 'a12'], [11, 12], ['c11', 'c12'], ['e11', 'e12']);

SELECT *
FROM visits;
/* results
┌────────────────time─┬─visits.a──────┬─visits.btime─┬─visits.c──────┬─visits.e──────┐
│ 2020-06-12 08:14:07 │ ['a1','a2']   │ [1,2]        │ ['c1','c2']   │ ['e1','e2']   │
│ 2020-06-12 08:14:07 │ ['a11','a12'] │ [11,12]      │ ['c11','c12'] │ ['e11','e12'] │
└─────────────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┴───────────────┘
*/
```

Additionally, see the article [Nested Data Structures in ClickHouse](https://www.altinity.com/blog/2017/8/30/nested-data-structures-in-clickhouse).

---

Comment: got it, but if i want to batch import such data structure from mongo, it will be complexd to transform.

Comment: there are two ways either create DB-schema that repeat JSON-schema (as described in the answer) or store JSON as strings and use [Functions for Working with JSON](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/). Also, both ways can be combined.